# connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2002

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I tried everything I found on internet, but cannot solve the problem on Ubuntu 11.04.

I tried these things:

- started mysqld manually using `sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld start`
- started mysqld using `service mysqld start`
- Checked it is running using `ps ax | grep mysqld` and got result `3419 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld`
- created the file manually at`/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`
- Gave rights to `mysql` user
- Tried to remove and re-install but it still do not work
- Tried `tasksel` to configure LAMP, every thing else works but mysql generate same error.

When run with `mysqld -P 3305` it generates the error

```
110630  0:24:24 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/nazar-studio.lower-test
110630  0:24:24 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/nazar-studio.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13)
110630  0:24:24 [ERROR] Aborting

110630  0:24:24 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Here is the mysql error log

```
10630  0:07:22 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
110630  0:07:22  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
110630  0:07:22  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
110630  0:07:22  InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
110630  0:07:22  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
110630  0:07:22  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
110630  0:07:23  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 0
110630  0:07:23  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
110630  0:07:28  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
110630  0:07:28 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
110630  0:07:28  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
110630  0:07:28  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
110630  0:07:28  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
ERROR: 1064  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE user ADD column Show_view_priv enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT ' at line 1
110630  0:07:28 [ERROR] Aborting

110630  0:07:28  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
110630  0:07:34  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
110630  0:07:34 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

110630  0:07:34 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
110630  0:07:34  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
110630  0:07:34  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
110630  0:07:34  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
110630  0:07:34  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
110630  0:07:39  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
110630  0:07:39 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
110630  0:07:39  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
110630  0:07:39  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
110630  0:07:39  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
ERROR: 1050  Table 'plugin' already exists
110630  0:07:39 [ERROR] Aborting

110630  0:07:39  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
110630  0:07:44  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
110630  0:07:44 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

110630  0:18:30 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
110630  0:18:30  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
110630  0:18:30  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
110630  0:18:30  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is 'start').
Use --verbose --help to get a list of available options
110630  0:18:30 [ERROR] Aborting

110630  0:18:30  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
110630  0:18:35  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
110630  0:18:35 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

How can this error be resolved?

Comment: Suggest editing your question to include the steps you've attempted, lest we duplicate those failed attempts for you!

Comment: +1 Thorough question, good detail, and you've actually tried to solve it yourself.

Comment: How are you trying to connect to it, though?

Comment: `mysql -uroot -p`, it gave error error, if i use command `sudo service stop mysql`, it is done correct. But if i use command `sudo service start mysql` it took so log time around 20 seconds.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did experiments and finally solve it with these commands

```
sudo chown mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/ -R
sudo chmod g+rw /var/lib/mysql/ -R
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant &
```

It get running...... Hurraaahhhhhhhhhh!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It was working at that time. But after restart same error occurs again and this time it do not work.

Comment: For each time i restart i need to enter these commands and it get running.

Answer (score 4):

Your log actually tells you the issue:

> mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is 'start').

Just start the daemon without the word 'start'. Instead of:

sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld start

it should be just:

sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld

Answer (score 1):

It looks like either it can't create a file in /var/lib/mysql/. If you look at the errode 13, it is generally means permission errors.

1) Make sure that mySQL can write to the directory /var/lib/mysql and/or that mySQL owns that directory. Do a:

```
cd /var/lib ; ls -la | grep mysql
```

To be sure.

2) If you are trying to start with the mySQL user, start it with root instead (You probably are, but it's worth checking).

3) If you are running something like SElinux, make sure that you enable it for mySQL access. I doubt that is the case, but it's worth checking.

4) Small note: Don't create the sock file - mysql will create one once it is up and running properly. If it still in the run directory, delete it.

Comment: In other news, can somebody move this over to serverfault? This issue is more apropos for that forum.

Comment: It gave the following output `drwx------  3 mysql         mysql         4096 2011-06-30 00:18 mysql` means it is owned by mysql user and have read/write access. I am starting mysql with root user of mysql using `mysql -uroot -p`. And i had removed the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple mysql servers installed then make sure you run the correct MYSQL or change your path settings. For example:

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

I have XAMPP installed , the solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill the socket with (this may depend on your OS)

rm /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
rm: remove socket `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'? y
restart the service

service mysqld start

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
sudo touch /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

More background info here: https://askubuntu.com/a/127029