# "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, mysql-python

I am using mysqldb (the python MySQL) module..
But everytime I try to run. it gives me this error.

```
   super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through     socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

I think the issue is multiple mysql installed.. but I am no mysql expert.. actually besides python.. assume i have a very minimal knowledge of OS.. mysql.or any other thing, :)

I have also installed XAMPP on ubuntu.. and everytime i start the xampp module
But before I start the xampp server..
I always do the following..

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop (this is my clue that there is another mysql installed :D )
```

To start the XAMPP local host I do the following

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

And the error says

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

I am elaborating on all of the above just to demonstrate where the paths of what is relevant to solve this thing lives..
Can you please help me out.
Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
ps -ax
```

rreturns follwoing:

```
Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
1 ?        Ss     0:01 /sbin/init
2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
3 ?        S      1:45 [ksoftirqd/0]
6 ?        S      0:00 [migration/0]
17 ?        S<     0:00 [cpuset]
18 ?        S<     0:00 [khelper]
19 ?        S<     0:00 [netns]
21 ?        S      0:00 [sync_supers]
22 ?        S      0:00 [bdi-default]
23 ?        S<     0:00 [kintegrityd]
24 ?        S<     0:00 [kblockd]
25 ?        S<     0:00 [kacpid]
26 ?        S<     0:00 [kacpi_notify]
27 ?        S<     0:00 [kacpi_hotplug]
28 ?        S<     0:00 [ata_sff]
29 ?        S      0:00 [khubd]
30 ?        S<     0:00 [md]
34 ?        S      0:00 [khungtaskd]
35 ?        S      0:01 [kswapd0]
36 ?        SN     0:00 [ksmd]
37 ?        S      0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
38 ?        S<     0:00 [aio]
39 ?        S      0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
40 ?        S<     0:00 [crypto]
44 ?        S<     0:00 [kthrotld]
46 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
47 ?        S      0:05 [scsi_eh_1]
48 ?        S<     0:00 [kmpathd]
49 ?        S<     0:00 [kmpath_handlerd]
50 ?        S<     0:00 [kondemand]
51 ?        S<     0:00 [kconservative]
219 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
220 ?        S      0:48 [usb-storage]
253 ?        S      0:12 [jbd2/sda6-8]
254 ?        S<     0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
307 ?        S      0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
313 ?        S<s    0:00 udevd --daemon
549 ?        S      0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
678 ?        S<     0:00 [hci0]
698 ?        S<     0:00 [hd-audio0]
   `727 ?        S<     0:00 [hd-audio1]
  729 ?        S<     0:00 [applesmc-led]
  775 ?        Ss     0:00 smbd -F
  778 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
  784 ?        Sl     0:00 rsyslogd -c4
  792 ?        S      0:00 smbd -F
  796 ?        Ss     0:20 dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart
  807 ?        Ssl    0:16 NetworkManager
  814 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/modem-manager
  817 ?        Sl     0:03 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd
  854 ?        S      0:03 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s
  873 tty4     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
  877 tty5     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
  883 tty2     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
  884 tty3     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
  888 tty6     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
  900 ?        Ss     0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
  914 ?        Ss     0:13 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
  928 ?        Ss     0:00 cron
  929 ?        Ss     0:00 atd
  931 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd --udev
  946 ?        S<     0:00 [l2cap]
  978 ?        Ssl    0:00 gdm-binary
  982 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
 1079 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-simple-slave --display-id /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Display1
 1087 ?        S<     0:00 [krfcommd]
 1088 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -F
 1164 tty7     Ss+   42:06 /usr/bin/X :0 -nr -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-pkvNFp/database -nolisten tcp vt
 1200 ?        S      0:11 [flush-8:0]
 1314 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-session-worker
 1320 ?        Sl     0:22 /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
 1324 ?        SNl    0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit-daemon
 1431 ?        Ss     0:08 nmbd -D
 1490 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
 1496 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
 1515 ?        Ssl    0:00 gnome-session --session=ubuntu
 1548 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
 1551 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
 1552 ?        Ss     1:00 //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
 1557 ?        S      0:33 /usr/lib/libgconf2-4/gconfd-2
 1566 ?        Ssl    0:35 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
 1572 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
 1575 ?        Sl    36:41 compiz
 1579 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs//gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/mohit/.gvfs
 1584 ?        Ssl    5:19 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
 1586 ?        Sl     3:04 nautilus
 1587 ?        Sl     0:02 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
 1589 ?        SLl    0:19 nm-applet --sm-disable
 1590 ?        Sl     0:02 zeitgeist-datahub
 1591 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/2.32/evolution-alarm-notify
 1597 ?        Sl     0:17 gnome-power-manager
 1598 ?        Sl     0:00 bluetooth-applet
 1601 ?        Sl     0:03 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
 1619 ?        S      0:00 /bin/cat
 1621 ?        Sl     0:20 /usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd
 1627 ?        Sl     0:03 /usr/lib/evolution/e-calendar-factory
 1629 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.11 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
 1637 ?        Z      0:00 [zeitgeist-datah] <defunct>
 1649 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/pulseaudio/pulse/gconf-helper
 1653 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor
 1656 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/lib/udisks/udisks-daemon
 1657 ?        S      0:14 udisks-daemon: polling /dev/sr0 /dev/sdb
 1661 ?        S      0:31 syndaemon -i 0.5 -k -R
 1665 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
 1668 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
 1673 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/d-conf/dconf-service
 1683 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/compiz-decorator
 1684 ?        Sl     0:35 /usr/bin/unity-window-decorator
 1687 ?        Sl     4:22 /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service
 1698 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
 1700 ?        S      0:25 /usr/lib/bamf/bamfdaemon
 1704 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-session/indicator-session-service
 1709 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service
 1719 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
 1720 ?        Sl     0:04 /usr/lib/indicator-application/indicator-application-service
 1721 ?        Sl     0:05 /usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
 1722 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-me/indicator-me-service
 1746 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/lib/geoclue/geoclue-master
 1752 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-burn --spawner :1.11 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/1
 1825 ?        Sl     0:07 /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver --no-daemon
 1834 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-disk-utility/gdu-notification-daemon
 1876 ?        S      0:09 /usr/bin/python /usr/share/system-config-printer/applet.py
 1883 ?        Sl     0:06 update-notifier
 1917 ?        Sl     0:02 /usr/lib/unity-place-applications/unity-applications-daemon
 1919 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/unity-place-files/unity-files-daemon
 1944 ?        SLl    7:08 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
 1946 ?        S      0:09 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
 1948 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=zygote
 1975 ?        Sl     8:46 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=renderer --lang=en-US --force-fieldtest=C
 1998 ?        Sl    17:59 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=plugin --plugin-path=/usr/lib/flashplugin
 2243 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/system-service/system-service-d
10495 ?        S<     0:00 [xfs_mru_cache]
10497 ?        S<     0:00 [xfslogd]
10498 ?        S<     0:00 [xfsdatad]
10499 ?        S<     0:00 [xfsconvertd]
10505 ?        S      0:00 [jfsIO]
10506 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
10507 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
10508 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
10509 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
10510 ?        S      0:00 [jfsSync]
12826 ?        Sl     1:35 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=renderer --lang=en-US --force-fieldtest=C
13020 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-http --spawner :1.11 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/2
20440 ?        S      0:05 avahi-daemon: running [mohit-MacBookPro.local]
20441 ?        S      0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
24799 ?        Sl     1:14 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin -calc /home/mohit/Documents/vmf/VMF Test Reports/p
24900 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-network --spawner :1.11 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/5
24904 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-smb-browse --spawner :1.11 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/6
24910 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-dnssd --spawner :1.11 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/7
25340 ?        SNl    0:09 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=renderer --lang=en-US --force-fieldtest=C
25357 ?        SNl    0:04 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=renderer --lang=en-US --force-fieldtest=C
25772 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main -c config_file=/etc/po
25774 ?        Ss     0:07 postgres: writer process                                                                  
25775 ?        Ss     0:05 postgres: wal writer process                                                              
25776 ?        Ss     0:01 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                     
25777 ?        Ss     0:01 postgres: stats collector process                                                         
25863 ?        Sl     0:14 gnome-terminal
25868 ?        S      0:00 gnome-pty-helper
25869 pts/0    Ss+    0:00 bash
25928 ?        Sl    16:19 /usr/lib/firefox-8.0/firefox
25966 ?        Sl     2:47 /usr/lib/firefox-8.0/plugin-container /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so -gre
26057 pts/1    Ss     0:00 bash
26190 pts/2    Ss+    0:00 bash
26606 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-computer --spawner :1.11 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/8
27198 ?        S      0:00 [migration/1]
27200 ?        S      0:07 [ksoftirqd/1]
27201 ?        S      0:00 [migration/2]
27203 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
27204 ?        S      0:00 [migration/3]
27206 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
27225 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u:44]
27226 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u:45]
27251 ?        S      0:01 [kworker/2:0]
27252 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/3:1]
27317 ?        Sl     1:42 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=renderer --lang=en-US --force-fieldtest=C
27429 ?        SNl    0:05 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=renderer --lang=en-US --force-fieldtest=C
27466 ?        SNl    0:05 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=renderer --lang=en-US --force-fieldtest=C
27560 ?        SNl    0:21 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=renderer --lang=en-US --force-fieldtest=C
27607 ?        SNl    0:07 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=renderer --lang=en-US --force-fieldtest=C
27657 ?        S      0:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -4 -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action -pf /var/run/dhclien
27681 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/e-addressbook-factory
27686 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
27688 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-logger
28186 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/usbmuxd -u -U usbmux
28187 ?        S<     0:00 udevd --daemon
28188 ?        S<     0:00 udevd --daemon
28196 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-afc --spawner :1.11 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/9
28200 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-afc --spawner :1.11 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/10
28212 ?        S      0:02 [kworker/1:0]
28864 pts/3    Ss     0:00 bash
28923 pts/3    T      0:00 sudo easy_install Flasj
28927 pts/3    T      0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/easy_install Flasj
28992 ?        Sl     0:02 file-roller /home/mohit/Downloads/Archive.zip
29044 pts/5    Ss+    0:00 bash
29142 ?        Sl     0:00 file-roller /home/mohit/Downloads/Archive (1).zip
29152 ?        Sl     0:02 file-roller /home/mohit/Downloads/Archive (1).zip
29185 ?        S      0:01 [kworker/0:3]
29243 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:1]
29251 pts/2    T      0:00 python
29271 pts/1    Sl+    0:09 ./sublime_text
29507 pts/5    T      0:00 sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
29509 pts/5    T      0:00 /bin/sh -e /etc/init.d/mysql start
29513 pts/5    T      0:00 start mysql
29562 ?        SNl    0:09 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=renderer --lang=en-US --force-fieldtest=C
29632 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/2:2]
29633 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/3:0]
30030 pts/0    T      0:00 sudo chown mysql:root /var/run/mysqld
30148 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/1:3]
30997 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/1:1]
31015 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:2]
31812 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/1:2]
31853 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:0]
32315 pts/5    T      0:00 sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
32316 pts/5    T      0:00 /bin/sh -e /etc/init.d/mysql start
32320 pts/5    T      0:00 start mysql
32356 pts/3    R+     0:00 ps -ax
```

Comment: Have you checked that mysql is running (shows up in `ps -ax`?), did you verify that the socket file is where python is looking for it?

Comment: @MarcB Hi.. Thanks for the reply. I get the following response..?ANy clues what am i doing wrong

Comment: I see multiple mysql start requests, but no instances of 'mysqld', which means it's not running. The only 'mysqld' mention is part of a chown command.

Comment: @MarcB: probably a very lame question.. but how do i start mysqld.. Regarding mysqld chown instatnce.. i was trying out the solution of this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525917/connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket

Comment: @Jason: I get this message      start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.305" (uid=1000 pid=32751 comm="start mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init"))

Comment: try `sudo service mysql start`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aaghh a stupid overlooking of facts on my part.. 
In the question I did said that I am stopping the default mysql.. before starting the xampp mysql..
but forgot to restart it.. 
and unfortunately

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

wont work
you have to do

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently XAMPP has it's socket in a different place, so you need to explicity say where the socket is, since it's not at /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock. This will be something like:

```
kwargs2['unix_socket'] = '/some/other/path/mysqld.sock'
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
```

You might find the socket with the command:

```
find /opt/lampp -name "*.sock"
```

Comment: @ifagundes: Hi.. the find command doesnt returns anything... :(

Comment: well, this means that xampp does not keep it there. I undestood that you wanted to use mysql provided by xampp, not the one from ubuntu. As you mentioned below, once you start mysql from Ubuntu, the socket is found, if you want to use other mysql installation, you must find the correct socket path. Other option is to connect by network to 127.0.0.1 in correct port (usually 3306).