# Mountain Lion: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I installed mysql via homebrew. I ran the two commands brew suggests:

```
unset TMPDIR

mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
```

When I tried to run the mysql_secure_installation script, I receive this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

A separate thread led me to believe it had to do with permissions: [connect to local MySQL server through socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525917/connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket)

I ran the suggested commands substituting their mysql directory with

```
/usr/local/var/mysql
```

Yet, the problem persists. Help!

Answer (score 2):

Your socket is probably being created in a non-standard location. My Homebrew installation creates it in `/tmp/mysql.sock` for instance.

If you can connect to the server over the TCP/IP socket, run this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%sock%';
```

Otherwise, try to look for it somewhere on your system:

```
find / -name mysql.sock
```

Comment: I'm getting a lot of Permission Denied messages:


find: /private/var/spool/postfix/saved: Permission denied
find: /private/var/spool/postfix/trace: Permission denied
find: /private/var/tmp/launchd: Permission denied
find: /System/Library/DirectoryServices/DefaultLocalDB/Default: Permission denied
find: /System/Library/User Template: Permission denied

Comment: That's normal if you're not using `find` as `root`. If this is a problem, try `sudo find / -name mysql.sock` instead.

Comment: Just adding on to the find command...putting 2> /dev/null will make the output more pretty by not displaying error messages.  Full command would then be: find / -name mysql.sock 2> /dev/null

Answer (score -2):

What is the default socket defined in /etc/php.ini?

Try running

```
cat /etc/php.ini | grep "mysql.default_socket"
```

Comment: This is a MySQL question. What would `php.ini` have to do with anything?